# OSX: Open file with shortcut in file browser in Coda IDE

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, coda

Coda IDE has a file browser area, where it's pretty nice to navigate with arrows through directories. But how to open a file with shortcut? Couldn't find this anywhere.. =/ 2 Years I'm using mouse for this, it's annoying as hell

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use your arrows to move the selection to a file, which opens automatically?

Comment: i don't want to open each file automatically. i mean why do i need to open it automatically if I'm just going through 100's of file with arrows..? and all 100 files will be opened? I disabled this feature. better just to navigate to your file and press some shortcut to open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@holms: If you press ctrl+q it will open a small quick open window. If you type the first few letters of the file you have highlighted and hit enter again your file will open, no mouse needed. To my knowledge that's the only way to remove the mouse from your equation.

Cheers!~Chris

Comment: nice work around.. still it very strance that cmd+o give me file_open window.. instead of just opening that file which is highlighted in file browser

Comment: anyway this is not right, `sublime text 2` comes up, better then coda anyway =)

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered this shortcut - seems to be a general mac thing but <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> works for me.

Comment: Niche and old... but still helpful in 2019.